# Import "airflow" could not be resolved

Tags: python, python-3.x, airflow, airflow-2.x

VSCode is not able to import airflow modules.

[image: VSCode Error]

`Python == 3.10.6`,
`apache-airflow == 2.5.3`

Airflow server is working fine, the DAGs can be created, but pylint and pylance are saying that airflow can not be imported.
Airflow is configured without docker.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] extracted from your code. Also, provide the instructions for running it and the output it produces. Use text, not images. Perhaps also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 7):

This is a classic VSCode problem: the issue here is the "interpreter" (you can read more about it [in the docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments)). Basically, VSCode uses a version of python to lint and interpret your code in the IDE, but when the interpreter's version doesn't match the version where you've installed a package, you get issues like this.

I would recommend doing the following steps:

1. In your terminal (or wherever you installed `airflow`), run `pip freeze` and confirm that `airflow` was indeed installed - if it wasn't, install it.
2. In your terminal, run `which python` or `which python3`, depending on what version of python you have. This will tell you what to set your VSCode interpreter to.
3. Open up your interpreter selection menu (see the picture - first click where the red arrow points, which should be the version number of python it's using, then click where the blue arrow points). Make sure the interpreter matches the version you ran locally.

[image: VSCode Interpreter View]

4. Sometimes these changes work right away, but usually you have to completely quit and reopen VSCode for them to take effect, so save your changes, exit, and reopen VSCode.

Comment: Hello, I forgot to mention that I am using WSL2 and airflow is running on virtual environment built on WSL2. Therefore python interpreter selection explorer can not see/find my python file, it simply searches for exe file (windows) not Ubuntu extension.

Comment: I was facing the same issue. Thanks for the awesome direction!